# What is the process „Tornit“? It wants to access Safari documents & passwords

Tags: applications, activity-monitor, malware

I was using Safari a couple of days ago, when I got a pop-up window:

> Tornit wants to control Safari and access your documents and passwords.
>   Do you allow it?

I clicked No.

Tornit is a process I can find in the activity monitor. I’ve generated a log. It’s too long to post, so here’s a Pastebin:

[Analysis of „Tornit"](https://pastebin.com/YURjRexj)

There’s absolutely no information about this process in the web. I’d like to know whether I can let Tornit access Safari or not, and how to cancel my blockade of the process, if it is harmless.

I use BitTorrent from time to time, and I thought the name **Tor**nit could be derived from **Tor**rent.

– masOS Mojave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tornit seems to be located in `~/Library/UpdateMac`, which one normally associates with where [MacKeeper](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=mackeeper) likes to hide its more shady tools. MacKeeper itself is a [potentially unwanted program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentially_unwanted_program) that one usually associates with malware-like behaviour and is something I would never want on a computer. Run a [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com) scan to completely remove this application.